# "Load More.." not working in PFQueryTableViewController with Sections - Parse & Swift 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have implemented PFQueryTableViewController with Sections as given here --> https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections .

However, when I enable pagination and I try to run `self.loadNextPage()` I get this error :-

> "attempt to delete row 10 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows
>   before the update".

This is when number of rows for pagination is set to 10.

I think this is because the `loadNextPage()` function is designed for rows and not sections hence it's trying to delete the last row and not the last section.

Does anyone have a working implementation of this with sections?

Here is the source for the Header file :- 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/blob/master/ParseUI/Classes/QueryTableViewController/PFQueryTableViewController.m

Thanks in advance.